# Pagination Unable to toggle list Items and unhide items

Tags: javascript, pagination

I try to do pagination with onclick event by toggling active list and show list's item which on active state while hiding non-active list.

I test it already and my HTML and CSS code were doing just fine. I think there's some problem with my Javascript code and I don't know what is it.

```js
$(".pagination li").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    // hide all .block elements
    $( ".block" ).hide();
    // show .block with the same index as clicked li
    $( ".block" ).eq( $( this ).index() ).show()
});
```

```css
.pagination {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pagination li.active {
  background: #003580;
  color: white;
}

.block {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="first active">1</li>
  <li class="second">2</li>
  <li class="third">3</li>
</ul>
<div class="block first">abc</div>
<div class="block second">123</div>
<div class="block third">!@#</div>
```

Can someone show me how to troubleshoot this problem? Or maybe some other ways on how to implement this concept.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine when I put it into a script block. What's wrong with it? Could you post an error message or other clue?

Comment: Try check your browser console, yes code is work.